# Can't insert data into Sqlite database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

This is the code for me to insert data into the database. Everything is fine with no errors. I typed everything that I need supposedly.

But somehow I am still not able to insert the data. What is the reason? When I check the database, the table `cart` is empty.

```
public void insertrecord() {
    Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    long rowId = bundle.getLong("rowId");

    mydb2 = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    myCursor2 = mydb2.query(Dbhelper.CART_NAME, allColumns2, "ID_=" + String.valueOf(rowId), null, null, null, null);

    myCursor.moveToFirst();
    if (!myCursor.isAfterLast()) {
        String cartname = (myCursor.getString(myCursor.getColumnIndex(Dbhelper.COLUMN_TITLE)));
        mydb2.execSQL("insert into cart(id_, cartRecord) VALUES(" + rowId + ", '" + cartname + "');");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? 
First you find the row with `id_ = rowId` and then if this row exists you want to insert another row with the same `id_`? 
Isn't this `id_` `UNIQUE` in the table? 
Maybe you should do the opposite, meaning if this `id_` does not exist then insert the new row with some value for `cartname`:

```
if (myCursor.getCount() == 0) {
    mydb2.execSQL("insert into cart(id_, cartRecord) VALUES(" + rowId + ", '" + cartname + "');");
}
```